# What would be the best practice to design a complex query with many transitive association in Spring using JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am wondering what would the best practice to design the repository classes of a Spring web application using JdbcTemplate that can execute complex queries with many transitive associations/relationships?

Would design it by:

1. Implementing each individual repository class to represent an individual database table? And then you build complex queries on top of them? OR
2. Implementing the complex queries as individual classes and create a customized data objects to hold their data?

My question are

1. Which approach would choose? And why?
2. If none of the above approaches is appropriate, what differently would you do?
3. If the you’re using JPA what would do differently?